# DB2 Error executing sql statement: [SQL0104] Token ) was not valid

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I am getting the following error from DB2, using custom driver: `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver`

> Error executing sql statement: [SQL0104] Token ) was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.; Caused by: [SQL0104] Token ) was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.

Narrowed it down to this bit which works in SQL server, we are a bit stumped as syntax appears fine.

```sql
SELECT CASE
          WHEN Abs(ho.ohmisc) > 0 
          THEN
               (
                  SELECT LEFT(s, Translate('%[^0-9]%', s) - 1)
                  FROM (
                     SELECT Substr(
                         ohunpo, 
                         Translate('%[0-9]%', ohunpo), 
                         Len(ohunpo)
                     ) AS s 
                  ) t 
               )
          ELSE odrord
       END ODRORD
FROM   qs36f.hoehead HO
QS36F.hoehead  HO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `FROM`

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN Abs(ho.ohmisc) > 0 
          THEN
               (
                  SELECT LEFT(s, Translate('%[^0-9]%', s) - 1)
                  FROM (
                     SELECT Substr(ohunpo, 
                                   Translate('%[0-9]%', ohunpo), 
                                   Len(ohunpo)
                                   ) AS s 
                        -- **You need a FROM here**
                        ) t 
               )
          ELSE odrord
       END ODRORD
FROM   qs36f.hoehead HO
QS36F.hoehead  HO
```

But that's not your only issue...

This is not valid either, are you trying to join the table to itself?

```
FROM   qs36f.hoehead HO
QS36F.hoehead  HO
```

Your embedded selects likely aren't right either....but without knowing your table structure and seeing some example source data and what you're wanting as output, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful to me. 

Adding the FROM

as s
from QS36F.hoehead) t )

solved the big issue. Still some syntax problems, but I think the db guy can take it from here.

This was bad copy/paste on my part.

FROM   qs36f.hoehead HO
QS36F.hoehead  HO